# Using two simple pendulums to estimate $g$

Tags: gravity, acceleration, vibrations

I know that using the period expression for a simple pendulum we can have an estimation of the acceleration of gravity $g$. I encountered the following question

> One way of measuring the terrestrial gravitational field $g$ at a given
>   point on the surface of the Earth is to have two ropes of different
>   but known lengths $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$. Any two masses are attached to these two cords and
>   the latter are suspended from the ceiling. Explain by a procedure how
>   the observation of these two pendulums makes it possible to estimate a
>   value for $g$.

The pendulums not connected in any way the only method that I see is to combine the expressions for the periods $T_1=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{\ell_1}{g}}$ and $T_2=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{\ell_2}{g}}$ so that obtaining the expression

\begin{equation} 
g=4\pi\frac{\sqrt{\ell_1\ell_2}}{T_1T_2}
\end{equation}

But I am wondering what this extension has more to offer that the simple single case? What am I missing here?

Comment: $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ are the lengths of the ropes not the distances from the support to the centre of mass of the two masses.

Comment: @Farcher The masses are considered points (it is a from an introductory mechanics course).

Comment: Farcher is still right. The masses are points, located at their CoGs.

Comment: @Gert Sorry but still I cannot grasp the difference. Can your elaborate more? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $l$ is the length of the rope *plus* the distance between the end of the rope and the CoG of the mass. That's what Farcher meant.

Comment: I think that you're correct that in principle you should be able to get a good measurement of g from just one pendulum by measuring its period T and knowing the rope length $l$. The nice thing about using multiple pendulums with different lengths of $l$ is that you can plot up the measured time periods T and versus $\sqrt l$ and see if the points lie on a straight line. If they do then you have more confidence that the model is correct and that you haven't overlooked anything or have significant measurement errors. The desired g is then related to the slope of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly, using one pendulum you can do the experiment to find the $g$ value. But the time period $T$ you measured should have some error any way. While finding $g$ you have to square the time period in single pendulum case. Using two pendulum  you don't have to do that. Just multiply the two time period. The error caused in the former case is more than the latter one(squaring a single time period value than multiplying two observed value).